# Export SQL database to MDF to use as local file in VS2010 error

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, mdf

I want to get a MS SQL database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to an MDF to use locally in a program. I detached the DB and manually copied the MDF, but whenever I try to open it up in VS, I get an error that it cannot be opened because it is version 661. I received the data as a CSV, used Access to import it and exported it to a local SQL implementation. Most importantly, what am I doing wrong?

Also, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to create an MDF file from a CSV?

Thanks!

Spencer

Comment: The "Detach the MDF" approach is correct - the error you're getting means that you seem to be trying to use a newer SQL Server MDF file (e.g. 2008) on an older SQL Server version (e.g. 2005) - this will **never** work - but it has **nothing** to do with detaching and copying the MDF file

Comment: I'm trying to import it into Visual Studio to use as a local database. This is all done on the same computer, I took a CSV file and imported it into Access. Used Access to fill my local SQL installation. Detached and copied the SQL database that Access populated, but when I imported into VS2010, I got the above error. I hope that makes better sense.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I said - the basic approach is OK - detach the MDF, copy the file, open it as a local database in Visual Studio.

**BUT:** it would appear that you're trying to use a SQL Server **2008 R2** MDF file, but the SQL Server version that Visual Studio 2010 supports/installs is SQL Server **2008** Express.

You cannot go from a newer SQL Server version (2008 **R2**) back to an older version (SQL Server **2008**) - this is not supported.

One possible way to solve this would be to explicitly uninstall SQL Server 2008 Express that Visual Studio 2010 installed, download the [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) version from Microsoft's web site and install it (as the `.\SQLExpress` instance, as did Visual Studio).

Once you have the same version of SQL Server - both on your main server as well as from within Visual Studio, then you should be able to achieve what you're looking for.